# nodemon app crashed

Tags: node.js, npm

Я пробовал использовать несколько ресурсов, но все еще не понимаю, что случилось? Я попытался удалить и снова переустановить npm.NOOB здесь, пытаясь следовать этому руководству по React: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/ я новичок. очень признателен, если кто-нибудь может мне помочь.

```
C:\Users\NILOY\workplace\seo_tool\server>npm start                                                                                                                                                                                              
> server@1.0.0 start C:\Users\NILOY\workplace\seo_tool\server                                                           
> nodemon src/app.js --exec npm run lint && node                                                                                                                                                                                            

[nodemon] 2.0.7                                                                                                         
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`                                                                            
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*                                                                                         
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json                                                                              
[nodemon] starting `npm src/app.js run lint`                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Usage: npm <command>                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
where <command> is one of:                                                                                                  
access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,                                                                   
clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,                                                                  
create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,                                                                 
edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,                                                             
install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,                                                             
login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,                                                            
profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,                                                              
run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,                                                                  
stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,                                                                      
uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,                                                             
whoami                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>                                                                               
npm -l            display full usage info                                                                               
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>                                                                             
npm help npm      involved overview                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:                                                                                  
C:\Users\NILOY\.npmrc                                                                                               
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value                                                                   
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config                                                                                                                                                                                                  
npm@6.14.10 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm                                                                                                                                                                                            
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/app.js --exec npm run lint && node",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.1",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: А зачем у вас в команде старта `lint` затесался? Вы хотите перед стартом прогнать линтер?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял чего хочет автор, то нужно просто использовать `prestart` скрипт:

```
"prestart": "npm run lint",
"start": "nodemon src/app.js",
```

тогда команда `npm start` запустит `start` скрипт только после успешного выполнения `prestart` скрипа.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts